# Python "cannot assign to funtion call"

Tags: python, list, syntax

I am terribly sorry for asking this question, as it has been asked multiple times before but because I'm an absolute beginner to python, I don't understand the underlying issue and am therefore unable to apply the concept to my own code. In these few lines I tried to make a funtion that shows all the vowels contained in a string.
in the second for loop, where I wanted to make a string out of the list l, it gave me the error "cannot assign to function call", when I tried to pick out a specific item from the list.
I'd be very thankful if someone could tell me how to solve this issue and explain what exactly this syntax error means.
`

```
word = str(input())
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
l = []
x = ''
for i in word:
    if i in vowels:
        if i not in l:
            l.append(i)
for i in v:
    l.__getitem__(i) += x #cannot assign to function call
    ' ' += x
print(x)
```

`

Comment: What is v ? You haven't assigned it yet

Comment: Where is `v` variable?

Comment: Why are you calling `__getitem__` at all instead of writing `l[i] += x`?

Comment: In addition to the other comments raised, it's best not to use `i` and `l` as variables in your code. They are tough to tell apart and are (traditionally) to be avoided.

Answer (score 5):

As the error says, you cannot assign to a function call. If, for whatever reason, you don't want to simply write `l[i] += x`, you would have to call the `__iadd__` method explicitly as well.

```
for i in v:
    l.__getitem__(i).__iadd__(x)
```

However, as `' ' += x` is also illegal, I suspect you are simply reversing the operands. The code should be

```
for i in v:
    x += l[i]
    x += ' '
```

but this entire loop is more properly (and efficiently) replaced with a call to the `join` method:

```
x = ' '.join(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us take the statement :

i += 1

This is shorthand for

i = i + 1

In these statements, i is a variable. It's value is being incremented by 1 and being reassigned to i. The same cannot be done with a function call. It is not a variable.